# Normal Distribution of a randomly selected sample

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> Suppose the score of each student in an exam follows a Normal distribution with mean $\mu=75$ and standard deviation $\sigma=0.8$. If we take a random sample of 20 of these students, then what is the probability that more than 2 students will score less than 74.4

I know that for a sample size $n$, the mean of the random sample remains the same ($\mu$) as the population but the standard deviation becomes $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$.

The thing which is confusing me here is this part: **probability that more than 2 students will score less than 74.4**

If they would have asked about the probability of the mean score of the 20 randomly selected samples being less than 74.4, then the solution was simple. This is what I would have done

$$
z = \frac{74.4-75}{\frac{0.8}{\sqrt{20}}}=-3.354 \\
P(z<-3.354) = 0.0004
$$

But how to deal with the situation which is asked in the original question. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In R: code `1 - pbinom(1, 20, pnorm(74.4, 75, .8))` returns
$0.9598072.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1. find the probability of one individual getting a score of 74.4 or less,
2. use the binomial distribution to incorporate sample size.